# Bash Escaping @ Symbol In Variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having an issue with an if statement in a Bash script. Here's the code:

```
if [[ "$AppleID" -ne "" ]]; then
    echo "<result>${AppleID}</result>"
else
    echo "No user logged in."
fi
```

Assuming `$AppleID` is a string with a value of "test@email.com", the error message is as follows:

```
[[: test@email.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@email.com")
```

I've tried using sed to escape the characters, like this:

```
if [[ `echo $(printf '%q' $AppleID) | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'` -ne "" ]]; then
```

But I get the same error. How do I escape the @ symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-ne` is for comparing integers. You want `!=`, or better yet, just use `-n` (which tests if its argument is a non-empty string):

```
if [[ -n "$AppleID" ]]; then
    echo "<result>${AppleID}</result>"
else
    echo "No user logged in."
fi
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to bash... :) Thank you very much!